# OutOfMemoryException, Result of Loop/While?

Tags: c#, exception, memory, out-of-memory, unhandled

I'm working on a project in C#, for which one of the questions is to make a program that receives a Stack and returns a new Stack with the digits that appear in that stack (every digit that appears will be in the new stack only once).

I made this code, which works pretty fine, but in the middle it just stops working and it gives this error "Unhandled Exception: OutOfMemoryException".

I was wondering what was the problem? From what I can understand it occurs because my program requires more memory than my computer can provide. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this or how I can improve my code to prevent this?

What can I do in general in codes to prevent this problem from occurring in the future?

Thank you very much in advance. :)

```
public static Stack<int> Stk(Stack<int> S)
    {
        int Num;
        Stack<int> New = new Stack<int>();
        while (!S.IsEmpty())
        {
            Num = S.Pop();
            while (Num != 0)
            {
                if (!Check(New, (Num % 10)))
                {
                    New.Push(Num % 10);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Original Stack: " + New);
                Num = Num / 10;
            }
        }
        return New;
    }

    public static bool Check(Stack<int> S, int num)
    {
        Stack<int> Temp = new Stack<int>();
        while (!S.IsEmpty())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stack Temp: " + Temp);
            if (num == S.Top())
            {
                while (!Temp.IsEmpty())
                {
                    S.Push(Temp.Top());
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Number found in Stack S!");
                Console.WriteLine("Stack S: " + S);
                return true;
            }
            Temp.Push(S.Pop());
        }
        while (!Temp.IsEmpty())
        {
            S.Push(Temp.Pop());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Stack S: " + S);
        Console.WriteLine("Number NOT found in Stack S!");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: *I was wondering what was the problem?* [Debugger Basics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/k0k771bt.aspx)

Comment: @Debugger Basics - rene - The program works fine (it does what it needs to do) but always in the middle it just stops working (freezes) and gives me the "Unhandled Exception: OutOfMemoryException" error.

Comment: To be honest, a program that consistently crashes is not really the definition of something that "works fine."

Comment: @MichaelRoy - My bad. I meant to say it was at least running, just not running correctly, not doing what it should do. Excuse me for my bad English, it's not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (num == S.Top())
{
    while (!Temp.IsEmpty()) // Infinite loop, Temp is never empty
    {
        S.Push(Temp.Top()); // Because of infinite loop, S is just going to fill up memory
    }

    //...
```

I'm not familiar with `Top()` on a `Stack<T>` but judging from the rest of the code it looks like it doesn't remove an object from your stack (the function I know of that does this is `Peek`). If that's the case you've got an infinite loop that fills up all available memory and ultimately runs out.

**Edit**: This answer focuses on the problem you're having. This smells like homework to me so I'm not going to rewrite it but I'd suggest paying at @ckuri's comment on this answer down below. It looks like you're doing a lot more work than you should. You may want to look at iterating the stack rather than popping to a whole new stack.

Comment: That seems like a simple spelling mistake; `Pop`.

Comment: I'd considered that, but he seems to be using it like it's `Peek`. Following the logic that seems to be what he's trying to do, and contains the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I learned of the command Top() which checks top value without popping it out of the stack. What I was trying to do is go over the whole stack but without losing it (whatever's in it) and so I pushed what I popped into another stack, and in the end returned it into the same stack. From what I've learned, if I pop the values in a stack which I transferred into that function inside of that function, the stack from the main function also gets affected. Correct me if I'm wrong?
(Sorry if it's a bit hard to understand, I can't figure how to explain it so well :P )

Comment: In which case, this is the answer. You've got an infinite loop. Also, I've never heard of `Top` where is it documented? The function I know of that does that is `Peek`

Comment: @RKei If you want to go over the stack without touching it, then just enumerate it by using `foreach`. If you want to make a copy of a stack you just write `var copy = new Stack<int>(sourceStack);`

Comment: @McAden - Yes!!! It worked! I didn't really understand why it was infinite and after you wrote the notes in your code then I understood. I just needed to change the 'Temp.Top()' to 'Temp.Pop()'. Btw, I learned that 'Top()' checks the top value of the stack without popping it. I believe it's like the 'Peek' you're talking about, but I guess my Stack<T> class it just programmed differently. So that was the fix for the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @ckuri - I haven't learned those commands yet ('foreach' and 'sourceStack') but it's good to know now how to make a copy of a stack. Thanks for the help though.